# To show Perelman $\mathcal{F}$ Energy in Ricci flow is invariant under diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

The following Perelman $\mathcal{F}$ Energy
$$\mathcal{F}(g,f) = \int_{M^{n}} (R + \mid \nabla f \mid^{2}) e^{-f} d\mu$$
is is invariant under diffeomorphisms. How to prove it? Or is there any references that gives complete proof of this conclusion?

Comment: Let $M, N$ be oriented Riemannian $n$-manifolds and the integrand be an $n$-form. If $\Theta$ is an $n$-form on $N$ and $\Phi: M \rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism, then $$\int_M \Phi^*\Theta = \int_N \Theta.$$ Therefore, it suffices to show that if $R_M, R_N$ are the scalar curvatures on $M$ and $N$, $\nabla_M, \nabla_N$ are the gradient operators on $M$ and $N$, $d\mu_M, d\mu_N$ are the volume forms on $M$ and $N$, then $$\Phi^*(R_N+|\nabla_N f|^2)e^{-f}\,d\mu_N) = (R_M + |\nabla_M (f\circ \Phi)|^2)e^{-f\circ\Phi}\,d\mu_M.$$ This is a straightforward calculation using the definitions

Comment: @Deane Thank you very much. I see

Comment: I omitted something. The metric $g_M$ is assumed to be the pullback by $\Phi$ of the metric $g_N$.